# django translation get_language returns default language in detail api view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, translation

this is the api which sets language when user selects some language this works fine.

```
class SetLanguage(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_language = kwargs.get("lan_code")
        translation.activate(user_language)
        response = Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, user_language)
        request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
        return response
```

viewset

here with this viewset only in the api `blog/{id}` the function `get_language` returning default language code but on other api it working properly. I am not being able to find the issue.
What might gone wrong ?

```
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.l_objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerilizer
    detail_serializer_class = BlogDetailSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "retrieve":
            return self.detail_serializer_class
        return super().get_serializer_class()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Blog.l_objects.filter(parent=None)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def childs(self, request, id):
        child_blogs = Blog.l_objects.filter(parent_id=id)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(child_blogs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

model

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        current_language = get_language()
        print(current_language)
        return super().get_queryset().filter(language=current_language)

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=100)
    objects = models.Manager()
    l_objects = MyManager()
```

**What can be the possible issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewset is defined as:

```
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.l_objects.all()
    ...
```

Here the point to be noticed is that your queryset gets defined at the module level. Hence your managers `get_queryset` is called. Considering there has been no requests yet `get_language()` returns the default language and this is then reused everywhere since the default implementation of the `get` method will just call the *viewset's* `get_queryset` which will then call `.all()` on the specified queryset hence your expectation of your *manager's* `get_queryset` being called each request doesn't occur and the default language queryset is reused everywhere.

To solve this you can just write a `get_queryset` method for the viewset, forcing creation of a new queryset each time:

```py
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.l_objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerilizer
    detail_serializer_class = BlogDetailSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.l_objects.all()
    
    ...
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks